# Connect SQL Developer to Redshift

Tags: sql, oracle, amazon-web-services, connection-string, amazon-redshift

I was able to connect SQL Developer to Amazon Redshift, using [Definitive Guide For Connecting Oracle SQL Developer to Amazon Redshift](https://blog.openbridge.com/definitive-guide-for-connecting-oracle-sql-developer-to-amazon-redshift-e204fd76e334).

But, visual query building and database object browsing is not supported. Has anyone figured out how to resolve these two issues?

Comment: It appears that Oracle SQL Developer is written for Oracle databases, which store their metadata differently to PostgreSQL. So, unless Oracle makes it work for other databases, it won't work.

Comment: Right, we offer redshift support only to help you migrate your data over to our Autonomous Data Warehouse Service